# Будут ли использоваться индексы в данном запросе?

Tags: binary, mysql, index, sql

Добрый день.

Есть таблица вида:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Будет ли при таком запросе использоваться индекс id?

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `id` = UNHEX(REPLACE('550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000', '-', ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Будет.